# How to get the subsection and subsubsection automatically in the header using scrheadings?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

### How to get the subsection and subsubsection automatically in the header using `scrheadings`?

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[
paper=128mm:96mm,
fontsize=12pt,
pagesize,
parskip=half-,
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ % Page margins settings
includeheadfoot,
top=3.5mm,
bottom=3.5mm,
left=5.5mm,
right=5.5mm,
headsep=6.5mm,
footskip=8.5mm
]{geometry}


\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearscrheadfoot
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{44,85,17}

\ihead{\rightmark}
\begin{document}
\section{This should appear in the header until it reaches a subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\subsection{Once the subsectin is reached this only should appear in the header}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

In the place of `\rightmark`, I want some comments which give subsections in the header.

### What I want?

In the header whatever the section or subsection or subsubsection appears that only should appear in the header not the section or chapter name which I introduced long back.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. The title says you want subsection and subsubsection, the example wants section and subsection, your final remark mentions *three* levels and chapter, while the class scrartcl has no chapter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to use `scrlayer-scrpage`. This package is the successor of the deprecated `scrpage2`. With both packages you can use `\automark` to define a section level that sets a right mark. But `scrlayer-scrpage` provides a starred version `\automark*` to define an *additional* section level that sets a right mark too.

```
\documentclass[
paper=128mm:96mm,
fontsize=12pt,
pagesize,
parskip=half-,
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ % Page margins settings
  includeheadfoot,
  top=3.5mm,
  bottom=3.5mm,
  left=5.5mm,
  right=5.5mm,
  headsep=6.5mm,
  footskip=8.5mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% activates pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\automark{section}
\automark*{subsection}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\rightmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{This should appear in the header untill it reaches a subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\subsection{Once subsection is reached this should appear in header}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

This can be extended for subsubsections:

```
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{section}
\automark*{subsection}
\automark*{subsubsection}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\rightmark}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your answer and the answer image... How to get the png as four pages together?(like in your answer) could you please tell me@esdd

Comment: And how to remove the numbering in header?@esdd

Comment: In the "View" menu of a pdf viewer normally something like a "Two page" and a "Scrolling" or "Continuously" mode can be choosen and then I take a screenshot.

Comment: To remove the numbering in header use `\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{}` and `\renewcommand*\subsectionmarkformat{}`.